# convert a string to persian number format

Tags: php, regex, string, number-formatting

I have a number string in Persian numbers for example

> ۱۱۲۵۱۲۰۱۲۴

which is **1125120124** in English numerical. I want to convert this string to number format separated by commas after every thousand for example

> ۱,۱۲۵,۱۲۰,۱۲۴

like when I do

```
number_format(1125120124); // it returns as 1,125,120,124
```

and

```
number_format(112512012); // it returns as 112,512,012
```

So actualy I want similar results as of number_format method. I just started regular expressions. Tried with very basic patterns but still no where near. Tried [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split string and concatenate it again with commas but does not seem to be right approach. I have a function where I pass a number that returns me that number in Persian characters. Sharing that too

```
function trans($num)
{
    $persian_num_array = [
    '0'=>'۰',
    '1'=>'۱',
    '2'=>'۲',
    '3'=>'۳',
    '4'=>'۴',
    '5'=>'۵',
    '6'=>'۶',
    '7'=>'۷',
    '8'=>'۸',
    '9'=>'۹',
];
    $translated_num = '';
    $temp_array=[];
    while ($num > 0) {
        array_push($temp_array,$num % 10);
        $num = intval($num / 10);
    }

    foreach($temp_array as $val){
        $translated_num.= $persian_num_array[array_pop($temp_array)];
    }
    echo $translated_num;

}
```

Comment: So, you have `$inpt = '۱۱۲۵۱۲۰۱۲۴'`, and want to get `$output = 1,125,120,124` (as a number)? Or `$output = "1,125,120,124"`?

Comment: No I have $input ='1125120124' , I change it to $temp_result = '۱۱۲۵۱۲۰۱۲۴' but the $final_result should be a formatted number. like '۱,۱۲۵,۱۲۰,۱۲۴'

Comment: Ok, so after translating your digits into Persian, you may use `preg_replace('~\d(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))~', '$0,', $temp)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As converting to Persian is a just character replacing, you can format number using built-in number_format() function and then replace numbers without replacing commas. Here is an example:

```
function trans($num)
{
    $persian_num_array = [
        '0'=>'۰',
        '1'=>'۱',
        '2'=>'۲',
        '3'=>'۳',
        '4'=>'۴',
        '5'=>'۵',
        '6'=>'۶',
        '7'=>'۷',
        '8'=>'۸',
        '9'=>'۹',
    ];

    $num = (float) $num;
    return strtr(number_format($num), $persian_num_array);
}

echo trans(1125120124); // returns ۱,۱۲۵,۱۲۰,۱۲۴
```

Comment: It is nice, just OP input is a string as far as I understood (from the comments). So, it should be cast to a number at first.

Comment: @Anton This is beautiful. Thanks. Is there anything similar in java script?

Comment: @TalhaMalik I think there are no problems with porting this function on Javascript. Take a look here: http://locutus.io/php/strings/strtr/index.html http://locutus.io/php/strings/number_format/index.html

Answer (score 5):

PHP's [Intl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extension includes a [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class that can format your number for a given locale.

#### Example:

```
$number = "1125120124";
$formatter = NumberFormatter::create("fa_IR", NumberFormatter::DEFAULT_STYLE);
echo $formatter->format($number);
```

#### Output:

```
۱٬۱۲۵٬۱۲۰٬۱۲۴
```

---

To force a comma to be used, it has a [`setSymbol()`](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.setsymbol.php) method.

#### Example:

```
$number = "1125120124";
$formatter = NumberFormatter::create("fa_IR", NumberFormatter::DEFAULT_STYLE);
$formatter->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL, ",");
echo $formatter->format($number);
```

#### Output:

```
۱,۱۲۵,۱۲۰,۱۲۴
```

---

Or if your input was in Persian, first use a [Transliterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php) on it.

#### Example:

```
$input = "۱۱۲۵۱۲۰۱۲۴";    
$transliterator = Transliterator::create("fa-fa_Latn/BGN");
$number = $transliterator->transliterate($input);
echo $number, "\n";

$formatter = NumberFormatter::create("fa_IR", NumberFormatter::DEFAULT_STYLE);
$formatter->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL, ",");
echo $formatter->format($number);
```

#### Output:

```
1125120124
۱,۱۲۵,۱۲۰,۱۲۴
```

Comment: Thanks. I checked that but I did not had the option to change php.ini so did not try it. Thanks for sample code though.